# Can I change an objects' size in Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have an object where  I load my data when clicked in the navigation. Is there a possibility to change the size of that object when loading a specific data?

```
<object id="box" width="250" height="250" data=""></object>
```

and the js, it loads the data but doesn't change the size.

```
document.getElementById("banner").onclick = function(){
   document.getElementById("box")
           .setAttribute("data", "sfw/danser.swf", 'height', 600, 'width', 150)

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set each attribute individually, the `setAttribute` function doesn't accept more than 2 arguments:

```
.setAttribute("data", "sfw/danser.swf")
.setAttribute('height', 600)
.setAttribute('width', 150)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute

The jQuery's version of the `setAttribute` function, the `attr` method, accepts an object:

```
$("#banner").on('click', function(event) {
   $("#box").attr({
       "data"   : "sfw/danser.swf", 
       "height" : 600,
       "width"  : 150
   });
});
```

Comment: Since it's tagged [tag:jQuery], it's worth mentioning that the jQuery way would allow `$("#box").attr({"data":"swf/danser.swf","height":"600px","width";150px"})`